# Help on the latin term Donandi

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Hello I am needing some guidance on Latin. We are rebranding our record label and we are passionate about giving back to the community. We have found the term Donandi and like it for our record label. We would be called Donandi Records. I can not find much online to help me see if this is an "ok" way to use this term for giving. What I find online is this:

Animus donandi  a´nēmūs dōnan´dē . â´nimus dōnân´dī. n.
“Intention to give.”An intention to give gratuitously; an intention to gift something to another.

If we like the name "Donandi" is it ok to just use this word and in a sense it still mean "giving" ?

In other words if we drop the Animus and just go with Donandi is it still ok to use it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

*Donāndī* has a few different meanings. It can mean "of giving", as in *modus donāndī* "method of giving" (or your *animus donāndī* "intention of giving"); this is called the *gerund* form. Or it can mean "must be given", as in *librī donāndī*, "the books that need to be given" or "the books need to be given"; this is called the *gerundive* form.

All in all, I think it's a good choice. It sounds nice and has a few different meanings in Latin, but all come back to giving or things being given.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your input!

Answer (score 3):

As Draconis has said **donandi** strictly means **of giving**. If you wanted to say just **giving** Latin would say **donandum**, which as Draconis has said has two meanings, **giving** and **(it) should be given**.

Comment: Great, thank you for your time and input!!